# Migrating/exporting data from OpenTSDB

Tags: csv, hbase, grafana, influxdb, opentsdb

I have locally hosted OpenTSDB on Ubuntu machine with whole bunch of data in it. I am currently using Grafana as a visualization tool for that data. 
I would like to export all of that data to some sort of a file either JSON or CSV/TSV is fine. Other option which would be acceptable is migrating data to InfluxDb since I know how to export from there.

I have tried few different things.
First I have upgraded my Grafana to Grafana 6 since it has Export tool. But that didn't really help because it would take forever to export every data series one by one.
I have also tried custom Python script using Happy Base to write from Hbase to CSV but failed to get that working.

I've also googled all other possibilities but didn't even encounter similar usecase. Maybe I'm missing something?